# expressJS is preventing me to post a resource

Tags: express

I'm trying to build a mini app in express, the "database" I'm using is a local array object file, I can retrieve resources from this "database" but for some reason I'm not able to post (push) a new object to this object array. This is how the code looks like:

***server.js:***

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const userRouter = require('./routes/user.js');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.text());

app.use('/user', userRouter);
app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`listening at ${port}`));
```

***user.js:***

```
const express = require('express');
const BBDD = require('./BBDD.js');
const userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.get('/:guid', (req, res, next) => {
    const { guid } = req.params;
    const user = BBDD.find(user => user.guid === guid);
    if (!user) res.status(404).send()
    res.send(user);
    next();
});

userRouter.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    let user = {};
    user.name = req.body.name;
    user.id = req.body.id;
    BBDD.push(user);
    next();
});

module.exports = userRouter;
```

And this is my local "database" file I want to perform logical CRUD operations:

***BBDD.js***

```
const BBDD = [{

            index: 0,
            guid: "1",
            name: "Goku"
        },
        {
            index: 1,
            guid: "2",
            name: "Vegeta"
        },
    
    ];
    
    module.exports = BBDD;
```

this is how I try to post a new resource, and this is the error I get:

[image]

It seems to be in order, but it won't work and can't find the bug.

Comment: try localhost:3000/user/ - does that work?

Comment: No, buddy, it dows not work

Comment: Remove the next() and send a response instead

Comment: That worked! can you tell me why it worked when I sent a response? "res.send()" was the last line as you said ¿Must every POST send something a response?

Comment: So next means that call the next handler that matches the request which in your case is nothing so you get a not found cause express couldnt find the next handler. Next is usually for middlewares not actual business logic handlers. And yes every request needs to send a response post/put/get/delete doesnt matter - an http request must send a response. Keep the next calls for middlewares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the next and send a response .express is having trouble finding the next matching handler because there is none